# Why data is not inserting in my sqlite database using ionic

Tags: sqlite, ionic4

I am making the todo app using ionic and the database is Sqlite. my app the data is not inserting please help me how to insert data in SQLite for browser.

**task.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var window;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {
  db: any;

  constructor() {

    let dbConfig={ name: 'my.db', location: 'default',version:'1',displayName:'fssfs',database_size:10000 };
    this.db = window.openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024); 
    this.db.transaction(function (tx) {   
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TASK (jobId unique,title,description,date,)'); 
   });  
  }
  saveData(jobId,title,description,date){
    this.db.transaction(function (tx) {   
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TASK (jobId,title,description,date) VALUES (?, ?,?,?,?'), [jobId,title,description,date]; 
   });

  }
}
```

**addtask.ts**

```
addTask(){

    this.service.saveData(this.todo.value.jobId,this.todo.value.title,this.todo.value.description,this.todo.value.date);
    console.log(this.todo.value.jobId,this.todo.value.title,this.todo.value.description,this.todo.value.date);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is slightly off. You have a '?' too much in your query, plus you are missing one ")".

```
saveData(jobId, title, description, date) {
    this.db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TASK (jobId,title,description,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
            [jobId, title, description, date],
            function (tx, result) {
                console.log('Query Success');
            },
            function (tx, error) {
                console.log('Query Error: ' + error.message);
            },
        );
    });
}
```